# how to search a string in structure variable ( C# )

Tags: struct

```
 public struct Items
{
    public string Id;
    public string Name;

}

   public Items[] _items = null;

if (_items.Contains("Table"))
                {
                    // i need to check the structure and need to return correponding id
                }
```

and am having a list of variables in my structure variable... 
i need to search a Name in the structure(_items) and i want to return the Corresponding Id.

how to do this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (Items item in _items)
{
    if (item.Name.Contains("search string"))
    {
        return item.Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: at this line  if(item.Name.Contains("search string"))  , its does not going into loop, it throws error, while checking the condition

Comment: @deep: paste your source code, i may think your collection is not declarated or you doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks Sivss, Got the ans by the following code.the error due to empty collection. got solved, thanks Ans: for (int i = 0; i < _items.Length; i += 1) // for each file { if (_items[i].Name == "Table") { string a = _items[i].Id.ToString(); } }